# SQLite - Help to Make Complicated Query More Efficient

Tags: sqlite, performance

The data is Financial data, structured in buckets, where one bucket (Rollup) can contain other buckets of data. As Example structure:

```
Rollup1 | Dept1
Rollup1 | Rollup2 | Dept2
Rollup1 | Rollup2 | Dept3
Rollup1 | Rollup3 | Dept4
Rollup1 | Rollup3 | Rollup4 | Dept5
Rollup1 | Rollup3 | Rollup4 | Dept6
```

There are 8 Columns of this, with Rollups and Depts scattered throughout (but the leaves are always single Depts). Approx 10k rows.

The goal of the Query Result is to show a single column with ALL Rollups, with variable logic to present certain Rollups normally, and modifying all other Rollups.

For example, if my variable contained "Dept4", my result would be:

```
Rollup1
Rollup3
NA - Rollup2
NA - Rollup4
```

In the real scenario, there are 3 variables which determine the display of the Rollup column.

Here is what I have, which functions as it should, however, the performance is VERY bad. 1 Query takes up to 5 seconds, which I would like to improve.

```
SELECT DISTINCT CASE
   WHEN "2" NOT IN
      (
         SELECT "2"
         FROM "Finance New"
         WHERE (@VAR3 = 'All' OR @VAR3 IN ("2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9"))
         AND (@VAR4 = 'All' OR "10" = @VAR4)
         AND (@VAR5 = 'All' OR "11" = @VAR5)
         )
   THEN
      'Z N/A - ' || "2"
   ELSE
      "2"
   END AS COL2
FROM "Finance New"
WHERE "5" <> 'All Applicable' AND "1" <> '9999'
AND "2" LIKE '9%'

UNION

SELECT DISTINCT CASE
   WHEN "3" NOT IN
      (
         SELECT "3"
         FROM "Finance New"
         WHERE (@VAR3 = 'All' OR @VAR3 IN ("2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9"))
         AND (@VAR4 = 'All' OR "10" = @VAR4)
         AND (@VAR5 = 'All' OR "11" = @VAR5)
         )
   THEN
      'Z N/A - ' || "3"
   ELSE
      "3"
   END AS COL2
FROM "Finance New"
WHERE "5" <> 'All Applicable' AND "1" <> '9999'
AND "3" LIKE '9%'
UNION

Etc, for each of the columns in the Rollup/Dept Tree report.
```

The inner select in each union query appends to the text based on the variable criteria. Sorting is done automatically. The last line before UNION (`AND "3" LIKE "9%"`) is to actually grab the Rollup. Rollups all start with 9.

Input parameters are labeled like @VARx.

I'm wondering if there is a more efficient way of performing this, assuming I cannot create a temp table and cannot change the structure of the data.

Thank you!

Comment: Is `'@COL3'` supposed to be a string or a parameter?

Comment: In SQL, single quotes `'` must be used for strings, and double quotes `"` for table/column names. SQLite accepts other quotes for compatibility with MySQL, but this makes this query unreadable; please fix it.

Comment: This is exactly how the implementation of SQLite that I'm using is expecting as Syntax. The '@VARNAME' is the implementation's representation of a variable. In other cases, the use of single and double quotes are as you state - Double Quotes refer to column and table names, single quotes represent strings.
I'll change the '@VARNAME' to just @VARNAME and note that this represents an input parameter.

Comment: Do you have any indexes? Could you add any? What are the columns' data types? Could you change them?

Comment: Which SQLite version do you have? Could you update?

Comment: I can add indexes, yes. I cannot change the data type. The implementation lists columns as containing either "String" or "Number". I don't know of the implementation version. The product vendor is Infosol and the product is Infoburst - DASH. It is used to create cache's of data and uses SQLite to query these caches.

Comment: `SELECT sqlite_version();`

Comment: That command does not work in this implementation.

Comment: Oh well. Such an enterprisey software wouldn't use a recent enough version anyway ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. All these ORs prevent the use of indexes.
   If at all possible, remove those `@VAR = 'All'` comparisons (or the other one) and create the SQL string dynamically, depending on the actual VAR3/4/5 values.
2. The LIKE prevents the use of indexes (because LIKE (or GLOB) would require TEXT affinity on the indexed column).
   Replace this with normal comparisons, i.e., replace `"col" LIKE '9%'` with `"col" >= '9' AND "col" < ':'`.
3. The UNION already removes duplicates; drop the DISTINCTs.
4. Without indexes, all these queries do full table scans.
   Create the following (covering) indexes:

```sql
    CREATE INDEX i_10_11_all on "Finance New"("10","11", "2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9");
    CREATE INDEX i_11_10_all on "Finance New"("11","10", "2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9");
    CREATE INDEX i_2_1_5 on "Finance New"("2", "1","5");
    CREATE INDEX i_3_1_5 on "Finance New"("3", "1","5");
    -- and so on for 4..9
```

Comment: I will try this on Monday. I am pretty sure I can implement all except the CREATE statements, but I'm going to give that a shot first. If I recall, there is a GUI option to use a column as an index, but I don't know if it will achieve what your statements above do.

Comment: If you cannot create multi-column indexes, at least try single-column indexes on all columns.

Comment: I can only create it on a single column, so I will try this. I haven't forgotten this, and will attempt this when I'm able to return to this project.

Comment: I am unable to add Indices with this implementation. I have sped it up by about a factor of 2, however, by redesigning the presentation of the data in order to break things apart into smaller chunks of data. I've added a way to request a specific subset of data in the report and modified my original query to incorporate this, so it searches through a subset of the table, rather than a full table scan. Let me know how I can leave you any rep. I suspect your solution would work, and I appreciate the information you've provided.